# Use client fingerprint to encode JWT token?

Tags: javascript, api, jwt, token, csrf

I'm wondering if it would be *best practice* to use a clients fingerprint as JWT-secret for encoding. However I couldn't find anything in the WWW concerning this question, but so far it makes sense to me to do it.

I'm thinking about generating a fingerprint client-side with JavaScript and sent it to the API with every call. The API should then use the fingerprint with a hard coded secret together for encoding and decoding the token.

Isn't this a good method to prevent CSRF? 
Or am I missing out on something else?
Or in general: What is the best way to prevent CSRF with JWT?
(I'm using PHP and VueJS, is there maybe a case related solution?)

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard about that.

A token is signed using a private key or a shared secret. The use of a fingerprint means you can correlate one (or more) fingers to a private key then compute a token.

However, this looks very similar to the [Webauthn protocol](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/) I am working with. When using Android devices, the browser can interact with the fingerprint/screenlock to authenticate the user. The data sent by the device is a JWT that can be verified using a Google API (see [Android SafetyNet](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/#android-safetynet-attestation)).